# Patten, String pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to extact key work from a string. The String format is as follows:

String is:  1) KEY, 2)Key , 3) Key : 4) Key: 5) Key. 6) Key

That is to say, after the key, there is either , . : or space as seperator. Can someone drop me a hint how to write regex?

Comment: Please show some code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String keys[]= "1) KEY, 2)Key , 3) Key : 4) Key: 5) Key. 6) Key".split(",|:|\\.");
// In regex '|' means or. So you can split by ',' or ':' or '.'
     for(String s:keys)
            System.out.println(s);
```

**Output**

```
1) KEY
 2)Key 
 3) Key 
 4) Key
 5) Key
 6) Key
```

Comment: Hi, if you want to match either `,` `:` or `.`, then `[,.:]` is the way to go.

Comment: @Robin Yaa, you can go that way also.

Comment: It would actually be a best practice: it's easier to read, and a `[...]` character class is quicker to match than a long `.|...|.`

Answer (score 1):

I think `string.split("regex")` is what you would need. Have a look at [the string docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).